# How to format arp -a output?

Tags: format, sed, arp

I'm trying to format `arp -a` output to my liking. For example at the moment it outputs:

```
MyRouter (172.16.3.x) at XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX [ether] on eth0
PC1 (172.16.3.x) at XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX [ether] on eth0
PC2 (172.16.3.x) at XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX [ether] on eth0
```

But I want it to output something like:

```
MyRouter;172.16.3.x;XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
PC1;172.16.3.x:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
PC2;172.16.3.x;XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

If I echo one of the lines with a **BAD** sed command that I created, it'll format the output to my liking but I can't use it on an `arp -a` command

Command:

```
$ echo "MyRouter (172.16.3.x) at XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX [ether] on eth0" | sed 's/ (/;/g' | sed 's/) at /;/g' | sed 's/ \[.*//g'
MyRouter;172.16.3.x;XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

But how can I format the `arp -a` output like this?

Comment: You're on the right track.  To get it to sed, you pipe arp -a to sed like so:  `arp -a | sed 's/ (/;/g' | sed 's/) at /;/g' | sed 's/ \[.*//g'`

Comment: Just to avoid giving unuseful answers, what's the reason you can't you use `sed` exactly?

Comment: I have No idea why it didn't work the first time, but thank you Terrance, this works. And also the selected answer works as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this one **sed** command version a try:

```
arp -a | sed 's/^\([^ ][^ ]*\) (\([0-9][0-9.]*[0-9]\)) at \([a-fA-F0-9:]*\)[^a-fA-F0-9:].*$/\1;\2;\3/'
```

Comment: works like a charm! I've needed this for the longest.

Answer (score 2):

With awk:

```
arp -a | awk -F'[ ()]' '{OFS=";"; print $1,$3,$6}'
```

Output:

```
MyRouter;172.16.3.x;XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
PC1;172.16.3.x;XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
PC2;172.16.3.x;XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

---

`-F'[ ()]'`: sets field separators to whitespace, `(` and `)`

`OFS=";"`: sets Output Field Separator to `;`